# pass string from C# to Javascript with Phonegap and Windows Phone 8

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

When developing a plugin, how is possible to get the result of my C# function to my javascript.

For instance having the echo plugin as in the [official cordova doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_wp8_plugin.md.html#Windows%20Phone%20Plugins)

When I pass a result from C# to Javascript calling

```
DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "{result:\"super awesome!\"}"));
```

Please How can I get the result inside my javascript code (how can I get: "super awesome")?

Comment: So you want to pass a variable from C# to JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dispacth the plugin result with status `OK` from `C#`, the win callback is called, and it brigns the result with this.

Example, your javascript plugin calls this from javascript:

```
cordova.exec(win, fail, "Echo", "echo", ["input string"]);
```

So you have to create a win function that will get the result:

```
function win(result) {
    alert(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just write the string directly :

```
<script> var JavascriptBlah = '<%=yourString%>'</script>
```

or use the method [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff402838(v=vs.105).aspx) to call a function to set the string :

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("yourStringSetter", "yourString");
```

[demo of a simple setter in js](http://jsfiddle.net/3h3d7kg7/)

[source for the first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553680/how-do-you-pass-variables-from-c-sharp-to-javascript)

Comment: Please could you edit it and kindly provide an example with echo plugin?

Comment: I dont know how works echo plugin. I asked you if you want to pass a string because I know how to do that. I use the second solution. If you can execute c# and if you have wrap your application in a webbrowser you could do it too.

Comment: I can execute a method C# using Phonegap, and call it via javascript (wrapping it). Then I want to pass a variable that I obtain into this method to JS. This is possible but not very well explained here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_wp8_plugin.md.html#Windows%20Phone%20Plugins.

Comment: here a full example on [github](https://github.com/MobileAppTracking/phonegap-plugin/blob/master/src/wp8/MATPlugin.cs)

Comment: looking a this github code, Please how to get a string (for instance "initTracker succeeded") from a js call? I am new to js

Comment: You can see the demo of a simple setter I posted. Maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757212/cordova-multiple-callbacks-in-windows-phone-8) can help you too.

Comment: This is the line of code to call in your JS : `cordova.exec(win, fail, "Echo", "echo", ["input string"]);`